# last n transaction in mysql group by user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have transaction table in which i am storing transaction user wise. 
i need last n transaction userwise. What is best way to find last n transaction group by userId. 
OR
to store last n transaction in other meta table is good way. Plz help me, because I have to send to client last 10 transaction userwise.

What is best solution. I am using mysql database.

**How can we create view of last 10 transaction of each user...is it possible??**

Comment: The best solution would have you showing us your table layout and some sample data along with what you expect as the output.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ and section *Select the top N rows from each group*

Comment: suppose user_id and amount...two column in database. i have to find or      give output to client last 10 trasanction of every user. what kind of solution you will suggest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using variables.

The row_number is assigned for each user transaction, and results are ordered by transaction date, so we can get only first 10 rows for each user.

```
select * from (
select *,
  @num := if(@user_id= user_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
  @user_id := user_id as dummy
from transactions,
(select @num := 0, @user_id:= '') d
order by user_id, transDate desc )T
where row_number <= 10;
```

Comment: will it work for multiple user simultaneously...is it not be too much costly..if suppose i have 10 million rows

Comment: Yes it will get resul for each user, and scan is done once , you can try out as long as u have index on user id and trans date

Comment: Is it possible to create VIEW using this type of query..can we create VIEW??

Comment: How we can create view of this result??

Comment: Add them as select , ( select @num := 0, user_id:= '') as t , then u can create it as view

Comment: 2 error- 1st error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause "...den if i am creating view of subquery..its throwing error- "View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter"...

Comment: you can probably create stored procedure.

Comment: ok will try...but i think its really great problem for mysql user...i m trying to get efficient solution